# How do I let vim wrap triple-slash comments?

Tags: c++, vim

I often use `gq` to wrap longer comments to within some number of characters, which works fine if I am using `//` or `/* /*` to comment my code:

```
// here is a simple comment that exceeds my line width 
// across multiple lines

// here is a simple comment that
// exceeds my line width across
// multiple lines
```

However, if I have triple-slash comments, e.g. for *doxygen*, it doesn't work:

```
/// here is a simple comment that exceeds my line width
/// across multiple lines

/// here is a simple comment that
// exceeds my line width / across
// multiple lines
```

`vim` seems to be including the last slash as part of the text, and not recognizing that it forms part of the comment. How can I fix this? Here is the wrapped result that I *want* to see when I select triple-slash comments and press `gq`:

```
/// here is a simple comment that
/// exceeds my line width across
/// multiple lines
```

Note that I don't want to affect the existing behaviour for normal `c++` comments.

I am using `vim 7.4.52`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Adding this to your `.vimrc` file should do the trick:

```
autocmd Filetype c,cpp set comments^=:///
```

Help about comment formatting can be found at `:h format-comments`.

Comment: Two years later, this answer is still very relevant and useful. :)